# Почему не заполняются поля метаданных при создании страницы через post запрос?

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

У меня wordpress сайт.
Я создаю страницу через пост запрос и сразу же заполняю вот эти поля метаданных для плагина AIOSEO:

```
Страница: заголовок
Мета-описание
Ключевое слово
Дополнительные ключевые слова
```

За заполнение полей метаданных отвечает эта часть кода в файле темы functions.php:

```
if (is_wp_error($result)) {
    write_to_log("Page creation failed with error: " . $result->get_error_message());
} else {
    $post_id = $result;
    write_to_log("Page created with ID: $post_id");

    // Заполнение AIOSEO поля "Страница: заголовок"
    $seo_title = isset($_REQUEST['SEO_TITLE']) ? substr($_REQUEST['SEO_TITLE'], 0, 60) : '';
    $update_title_result = update_post_meta($post_id, '_aioseo_title', $seo_title);
    write_to_log("Updating AIOSEO title: {$seo_title}. Result: {$update_title_result}");

    // Заполнение AIOSEO поля "Метаописание"
    $meta_description = isset($_REQUEST['META_DESC']) ? substr($_REQUEST['META_DESC'], 0, 160) : '';
    $update_description_result = update_post_meta($post_id, '_aioseo_description', $meta_description);
    write_to_log("Updating AIOSEO description: {$meta_description}. Result: {$update_description_result}");

    // Заполнение AIOSEO поля "Фокусный ключевик"
    $focus_keyword = isset($_REQUEST['FOCUS_KEYWORD']) ? $_REQUEST['FOCUS_KEYWORD'] : '';
    $update_keyword_result = update_post_meta($post_id, '_aioseo_focus_phrase', $focus_keyword);
    write_to_log("Updating AIOSEO focus keyword: {$focus_keyword}. Result: {$update_keyword_result}");

    // Заполнение AIOSEO поля "Дополнительные ключевики"
    $additional_keywords = isset($_REQUEST['DOP_KEYS']) ? $_REQUEST['DOP_KEYS'] : '';
   // $additional_keywords = isset($_REQUEST['DOP_KEYS']) ? implode(',', $_REQUEST['DOP_KEYS']) : '';
    $update_add_keywords_result = update_post_meta($post_id, '_aioseo_additional_keywords', $additional_keywords);
    write_to_log("Updating AIOSEO additional keywords: {$additional_keywords}. Result: {$update_add_keywords_result}");

    write_to_log("AIOSEO data has been updated for page ID: $post_id");
}
```

Страница создается правильно, но метаданные не вставляются. Почему?

Кстати,вот что пишется в фай-лог после создания странницы и вставки метаданных:

```html
 
   2023-09-13 12:38:41 - Password check result: success
    2023-09-13 12:38:41 - Starting page creation with action type: create_page
    2023-09-13 12:38:44 - Page created with ID: 43178
    2023-09-13 12:38:44 - Updating AIOSEO title:  Джон Дитон считает, что Джиму �. Result: 
    2023-09-13 12:38:44 - Updating AIOSEO description: Вчера Зак Ректор, известный в сообществе XRP, обратился к платформе микроблогов X (ранее и. Result: 315549
    2023-09-13 12:38:44 - Updating AIOSEO focus keyword: xrp. Result: 315550
    2023-09-13 12:38:44 - Updating AIOSEO additional keywords: биткоин,блокчейн,криптовалюты,биткоина. Result: 315551
    2023-09-13 12:38:44 - AIOSEO data has been updated for page ID: 43178
```

Comment: как вы определили что мета не поставилась? Пробовали запускать get_post_meta?

Comment: ещё вариант что пост в статусе ревизия, в таком случае мета уходит в родительский пост